# ANTLR4: matching token with same rule but with different position in the grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have the following statement I wish to parse:

```
in(name,(Silver,Gold))
```

- in: is a function.
- name: is a ID.
- (Silver, Gold): is string array with elements 'Silver', and 'Gold'.

The parser is always confused as ID and string array elements have the same rule. Using quotes or double quotes for string will help, but this is not the case here.

Also, predicates didn't help much.

The grammar:

```
grammar Rql;

statement
 : EOF
 | query EOF
 ;

query
 : function
 ;

function
 : FUNCTION_IN OPAR id COMMA OPAR array CPAR CPAR
 ;

array
 : VALUE (COMMA VALUE)*
 ;

FUNCTION_IN: 'in';

id
 : {in(}? ID
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;

VALUE
 : STRING
 | INT
 | FLOAT
 ;

OPAR : '(';
CPAR : ')';
COMMA : ',';

INT
 : [0-9]+
 ;

FLOAT
 : [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]*
 | '.' [0-9]+
 ;

SPACE
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;

STRING
 :  [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;

OTHER
 : .
 ;
```

Comment: It's not the parser that is confused, believe me. It always knows what to parse :-) So, what's the actual problem? What do you expect?

Comment: Is your input `Silver,Gold` correct ? Isn't it `'Silver', 'Gold'` ? Without apostrophes, there is no chance they are matched by the `STRING ` rule.

Comment: @BernardK: Yes. The grammar works with strings with quotes 'Silver' and 'Gold'. If I removed the quotes, the parser will think it's an ID.

Comment: @MikeLischke: I know I'm the one who is confused :)

Comment: Of course it's an ID -> LIT. Every piece of input starting with a letter is a LIT. I'm not sure if it is a good practice that a lexer rule calls other lexer rules. Why don't you make `value` a parser rule calling LIT instead of `STRING `?

Comment: @BernardK I edited the question. Now the ID has the same rule as STRING. The issue is, of course, ANTLR is picking the first lexer rule. would it be possible to use predicates to tell ANTLR that the ID only appear once and the rest is STRING?

Comment: It works with `function
 : FUNCTION_IN OPAR ID_COMMON COMMA OPAR array CPAR CPAR
 ;

array
 : value (COMMA value)*
 ;

value
 : ID_VALUE
 | INT
 | FLOAT
 ;

FUNCTION_IN: 'in';

ID_VALUE  : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]* {getCharPositionInLine() > 8}? ;
ID_COMMON : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]* ;
`. I prepare a solution with setType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to change the type of the token under some condition. Here seeing an ID for the first time in a line sets a switch to true. The next time an ID is matched, the lexer will execute the `if` and set the type to `ID_VALUE`. I wanted to reset the switch while entering the rule `function`, but it doesn't work :

```
function
@init {QuestionLexer.id_seen = false; System.out.println("id_seen has been reset" + QuestionLexer.id_seen);}
 : FUNCTION_IN OPAR ID COMMA OPAR array CPAR CPAR

ID=name1  seen ? false
ID=Silver  seen ? true
...
ID=Platinum  seen ? true
[@0,0:1='in',<'in'>,1:0]
[@1,2:2='(',<'('>,1:2]
[@2,3:7='name1',<ID>,1:3]
[@3,8:8=',',<','>,1:8]
[@4,9:9='(',<'('>,1:9]
[@5,10:15='Silver',<10>,1:10]
...
[@12,27:31='name2',<10>,2:3]
...
[@20,52:51='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:0]
Question last update 1336
id_seen has been reset false
id_seen has been reset false
line 2:3 mismatched input 'name2' expecting ID
```

.

That's why I reset it in the `FUNCTION_IN` rule.

Grammar Question.g4 :

```
grammar Question;

@lexer::members {
    static boolean id_seen = false;
}

tokens { ID_VALUE }

question
@init {System.out.println("Question last update 1352");}
 : function+ EOF
 ;

function
 : FUNCTION_IN OPAR ID COMMA OPAR array CPAR CPAR
 ;

array
 : value (COMMA value)*
 ;

value
 : ID_VALUE
 | INT
 | FLOAT
 ;

FUNCTION_IN: 'in' {id_seen = false;} ;

ID : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
     {System.out.println("ID=" + getText() + "  seen ? " + id_seen);
      if (id_seen) setType(QuestionParser.ID_VALUE); id_seen = true; } ;

OPAR : '(';
CPAR : ')';
COMMA : ',';

INT
 : [0-9]+
 ;

FLOAT
 : [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]*
 | '.' [0-9]+
 ;

SPACE
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;

OTHER
 : .
 ;
```

File t.text :

```
in(name1,(Silver,Gold))
in(name2,(Copper,Platinum))
```

Execution with ANTLR 4.6 :

```
$ grun Question question -tokens -diagnostics t.text
ID=name1  seen ? false
ID=Silver  seen ? true
ID=Gold  seen ? true
ID=name2  seen ? false
ID=Copper  seen ? true
ID=Platinum  seen ? true
[@0,0:1='in',<'in'>,1:0]
[@1,2:2='(',<'('>,1:2]
[@2,3:7='name1',<ID>,1:3]
[@3,8:8=',',<','>,1:8]
[@4,9:9='(',<'('>,1:9]
[@5,10:15='Silver',<10>,1:10]
[@6,16:16=',',<','>,1:16]
[@7,17:20='Gold',<10>,1:17]
[@8,21:21=')',<')'>,1:21]
[@9,22:22=')',<')'>,1:22]
[@10,24:25='in',<'in'>,2:0]
[@11,26:26='(',<'('>,2:2]
[@12,27:31='name2',<ID>,2:3]
[@13,32:32=',',<','>,2:8]
[@14,33:33='(',<'('>,2:9]
[@15,34:39='Copper',<10>,2:10]
[@16,40:40=',',<','>,2:16]
[@17,41:48='Platinum',<10>,2:17]
[@18,49:49=')',<')'>,2:25]
[@19,50:50=')',<')'>,2:26]
[@20,52:51='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:0]
Question last update 1352
```

Type <10> is `ID_VALUE` as can be seen in the `.tokens` file

```
$ cat Question.tokens 
FUNCTION_IN=1
...
OTHER=9
ID_VALUE=10
'in'=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! will this grammar works on generating a C# visitor/listener?

Comment: @AmrEllafy The advantage of ANTLR4 over previous versions/other parser generators is that the code has been moved into listeners/visitors. Nevertheless there are many circumstances where code is needed in the grammar, e.g. semantic predicates. The drawback of writing code in the grammar is that it must be written in the target language and must be changed for another target. See examples in [The Mega Tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial).